# Get number of components in placeholder, Sitecore

Tags: loops, indexing, components, sitecore, placeholder

I have a component that needs to know how many components thats currently added to the very same placeholder, this since it needs to update a value of an html-attribute based on its index within the placeholder.

Is there anyway to get either the number of components thats already added to a placeholder, or to get the current-renderers index?

Usually I would just use a simple for-loop and set the attribute, but since its a placeholder with components thats not an option.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
var placeholder = "my-placeholder";
var renderingReferences = Sitecore.Context.Item.Visualization.GetRenderings(Sitecore.Context.Device, true);
var renderingsInPlaceholder = renderingReferences.Where(r => r.Placeholder.EndsWith('/' + placeholder, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
var numberOfRenderingsInPlaceholder = renderingsInPlaceholder.Count();
```

Update: Changed search for placeholder key from `IndexOf` to `EndsWith`.

Comment: It will not work when you have placeholder called 'content' and second placeholder called 'content-left' (searching for 'content' will return both of them). It will also ignore components hidden by personalization.

Comment: @MarekMusielak Right, I changed it to `EndsWith`, this should work then. Also I think this will return the components which are currently visible, but I think this is what was asked. In my opinion it doesn't make sense to add any html attributes due to hidden components.

Comment: It won't work with `EndsWith` for 'main-content' and 'content'. I guess checking `Equals or EndsWith('/' + placeholder)` should work in standard Sitecore solution. If dynamic placholders are used, logic must be even more complex. Anyway, +1 for nice approach!

Comment: EndsWith returns a bool, so the `> -1` needs to be removed from that line.

Answer (score 1):

What is the HTML attribute you are trying to update and how are you planning on update this value? From C# code at render time? Or do you want to store this value when a component is added in the Page Editor and store the value against a Sitecore Item?

It depends on what your use-case is, but by suggestion for front-end use would be to execute this logic using JavaScript, otherwise you have to hook into Sitecore pipelines, find your HTML element and the add the attribute appropriately. Saving this value when a component is added means you need to r-run the login for the entire placeholder and update any stored values, since it will (should) be possible for the user to components anywhere...

Something like the following to add a order order data-attribute to a list of elements. If this is being used by another plugin the make sure you run this code before initializing your plugin.

```
// get element + its siblings
var $els = $('.selector').siblings().addBack();

// loop and add data-attr with index number
$els.each(function(index, element) {
    $(this).attr('data-sortorder', index);
}
```