# Sitecore - Different presentation details for same template

Tags: templates, sitecore

I will preface that this may not be the best use of a branch template, but it seems ok on paper, with a few drawbacks.

Sitecore 8, we have a Template called "Program."  Program needs the ability to either be a two-column (9-3 grid) or a full (12-col grid).  These basically represent a full version and a version with a right rail.

We want the content editors to be able to decide when they create the page whether they want a "program" or "program with right rail."  To set this up, we created two branch templates.  One that looks like this:

```
Layout: Base Layout

Renderings: Full (sublayout), Program Detail (rendering, dropped onto Full's placeholder)
```

And one that looks like this:

```
Layout: Base Layout

Renderings: Two-Column (sublayout), Program Detail (rendering, dropped onto Two-Column's placeholder)

Placeholder settings: Right Rail (allows right rail components to be added)
```

Then when the user right clicks on the "programs" item in the tree, they can pick one of the two options above and it creates the program item with the appropriate presentation details (again, either a full width or a two-col).

This all works, but the problem is if I ever have to change something on one of the branch templates, that change is not propagated to any items that were created based off of that branch like standard values works.  There's no "branch delta" that I'm aware of.

Is there a better way to handle this? In my head, it essentially sounds like I need standard values for a branch template, but I don't think that exists.

Another thought I had was to create an "Program Master" template and then create two templates that inherit from it, Program and Program with Rail. That way they would share the same data but would have different standard values and allow me to set different presentation details for it.  This feels a little dirty since I'd basically be creating a template to handle look and feel.  I hope I'm explaining this correctly, but if not I'll update with more info if I'm being unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately if you want to take advantage of "layout deltas," out of the box you would need to have a separate template with its own standard values, as far as I'm aware.

You could probably do something fancy with the `renderLayout` pipeline if you wanted -- e.g. Sitecore Zen Garden introduces the concept of "Designs" which are used to define default layout, and allow you to separate layout from Standard Values. But you're going off the reservation at that point.

Comment: Rats, I figured as much.  Since it's only two variations, I might just use one template that both of them inherit from and modify the standard values that way.  Thanks!

Comment: You know, the other thing I could do is make it one design but do a check to see if the right-rail placeholder has any controls on it, and if it does display the right rail.  Now I just need to find out how to get a count of controls added to a given placeholder ;)

Comment: If you're using webforms, that shouldn't be hard... just grab the placeholder by its ID and check for child controls!

Comment: Yeah, we're not using webforms, it's all MVC.  If I can help it, I stay away from webforms...I'm looking into trying this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27357167/get-number-of-components-in-placeholder-sitecore

Comment: Sweet, this worked...basically just add the markup if there are renderings in the rail...not perfect, but it works...I then only show the column if there are renderings OR we're in page editor mode...